# cURL gives me response, but some echo statements are missing

Tags: php, curl

i am trying to get content of dynamic php page via cURL

response on web seems like

```
James Bond

Male, 20 Apr 1991
Email: james@gmail.com
Mobile: 09394949494
Website: www.google.com
Address: Swat
```

but when i grap this url using cURL

curl gives me this

```
Female, 
Email: 
Mobile: 
Website: 
Address:
```

i am using this code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/cv/formats/1.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$my_html = curl_exec($ch);
echo $my_html;
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: if you use `View source` on the page, do you see the data? it may be dynamically loaded via Javascript, hence unavailable using cURL alone.

Comment: curl will only retrieve what it's sent. if the names aren't there, then you're not hitting the url properly (e.g. js/ajax calls after-the-fact, missing query parameters, etc....).

Comment: i am using plain php, no javascript, source code of target page is perfectly fine, still :(

Comment: You checked the source (loading it in the browser), but hexblot means when you check the source of the cURL page. If you see it there, then you just have hidden HTML entities that don't show, due to the lack of parent tags to style the content or they fall out of the visible DOM. Or try to echo `echo '<pre>'.$my_html.'</pre>';` (CDATA might also be a solution to check the retrieved data on page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA)

Comment: i checked the source code of curl page as well, still error...

Comment: problem is with echos none of the echos are working in curl page secondly i am taking these values from database...

Comment: i checked echo in test page and its working, but mysql driven data isnt displayed using echo in curl page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it,

i was retrieving data from mysql using session variable as condition checker, but that local session was not working for cURL requests so i had to pass my key as query string ;)